# AG-grid only show 11 records and update when the device width changes?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

The web service returns 21 records but only 11 rows visible at first. But if any change occurs to the with of the page it will render all the records

Below i listed versions.

Angular 5

ag-grid: ^16.0.1

ag-grid-angular ^16.0.0

I want to list all records when page is loaded. can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you  provide the code used to set the data in the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **rowBuffer** to your grid options

```
gridOptions: {
  rowBuffer: 100
}
```

RowBuffer is the number of rows rendered outside the scrollable viewable area the grid renders. Defaults to 20. Having a buffer means the grid will have rows ready to show as the user slowly scrolls vertically.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#miscellaneous